# Using regex in notepad++ to reduce json objects

Tags: json, notepad++

I have a huge Json file containing objects of the form:

```
{ "country" : "UK",  "city" : "London"  }
```

I want to limit the number of instances for each "country". Can I do this using regex?
I want to remove the whole block of object that contains "UK".
I tried something like `^{.*"UK".*},` 
(starts with `{` 
contains `"UK"` 
ends with `},`)
But this is wrong and I can't figure out the correct way.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you should not be using regex alone to handle JSON content, even less so if that JSON be nested.  If your JSON is always single level as you wrote above, then the following pattern might work:

```
\{[^}]*"UK"[^}]*\}
```

Replace the above by nothing, and do the find/replace in regex mode.

### Demo

Comment: Yes I was waiting for 8 minutes to pass, as it doesn't let me mark earlier!